# JSP query to decriment table value

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Iam trying to increment  or detriment value in table  . but query for increment is working , and detriment is not working.  i think something wrong in ifelse condition. or what should i do to correct it?
please help.

```
String a = request.getParameter("feedback");
session.setAttribute("a",a);
String b = request.getParameter("rate");
session.setAttribute("b",b);
String c = request.getParameter("comment");
int counter = 0;


if("Best".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){

    counter = counter + 2;
}else if("Good".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){

    counter = counter + 1;
}else if("Average".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){

    counter = 0;
}else if("Bad".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){
    counter = - 1;  

}else if("Worst".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){
     counter = - 2;


}


java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
     String DATE_FORMAT1 = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
     SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT1);
     String strDateNew1 = sdf1.format(now);

try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ranking","root","admin");
st=con.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("insert into comment(date,feedback,rate,comment) values('"+strDateNew1+"','"+a+"','"+b+"','"+c+"')");
st.executeUpdate("UPDATE cmtcount SET count = count + '"+counter+"'  WHERE type='"+a+"' AND rate='"+b+"'");
st.executeUpdate("UPDATE upload SET count = count + '"+counter+"'  WHERE types='"+a+"' ");




response.sendRedirect("commentinsert1.jsp?");

}

catch(Exception ex)
{
    out.println(ex);

}
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify this:

```
if("Best".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){

    counter = counter + 2;
}else if("Good".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){

    counter = counter + 1;
}else if("Average".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){

    counter = 0;
}else if("Bad".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){
    counter = - 1;  

}else if("Worst".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){
     counter = - 2;


}
```

To this:

```
if("Best".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){

    counter = counter + 2;
}else if("Good".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){

    counter = counter + 1;
}else if("Average".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){

    counter = 0;
}else if("Bad".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){
    counter = counter - 1;  

}else if("Worst".equalsIgnoreCase(b)){
     counter = counter - 2;
}
```

And instead of using:

```
st.executeUpdate("UPDATE cmtcount SET count = count + '"+counter+"'  WHERE type='"+a+"' AND rate='"+b+"'");
```

I'd recommend retrieving the values from SQL first in to variables then adding or subtracting the values and finally updating:

```
st.executeUpdate("UPDATE cmtcount SET count = '"+counter+"'  WHERE type='"+a+"' AND rate='"+b+"'");
```

Another tip, instead of:

```
counter=couter+1;
```

or

```
counter=couter-1;
```

You can do this:

```
counter+=1;
```

or

```
counter-=1;
```

Comment: i did but update query does not works. and for Best case 3 is added instead of 2  in table and negative doesnot works.

Comment: I edited the post, and also I'd recommend not using negative values, try sticking to positive values.

Comment: IF I NEED TO SUBSTRACT , WHAT DO I DO?

Comment: Well the problem is, does your sql field allow for negative values? Because it might be unsigned so a negative value would be saved as 0. If you can change it to a signed type, negative values would work. As for the Java side of things, integers are signed so it allows negative values by default.